# How to include post-hoc tests in a bootstrap loop in R

Tags: r, statistics, posthoc, statistics-bootstrap

The link to a related question ([How to randomly draw from subsets of data and bootstrap a statistic test in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125858/how-to-randomly-draw-from-subsets-of-data-and-bootstrap-a-statistic-test-in-r)) gives a nice example of how to bootstrap a statistics test on randomly drawn subsamples of data from a data frame. As an extension to this question, I would like to know how to perform post-hoc tests for bootstrap iterations of a statistic test in which a significant difference between groups is found.

Say I have plants sampled in three years (Y1, Y2, Y3). I wish to know whether the median length of plants differs significantly between years, using a Kruskal-Wallis test. If they do (i.e. p-value <0.05), I wish to know which years show significant differences, using Wilcoxon rank-sum tests. As I have some plants within my data frame for which multiple measurements were taken within a certain year, I will randomly draw one row for these plants within each year, for each stats test iteration to prevent pseudoreplication. The process will be repeated 10 times.

Example data:

```
structure(list(Plant = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L), Year = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L
), Length = c(110L, 99L, 124L, 154L, 112L, 129L, 93L, 132L, 178L, 
206L, 177L, 257L, 173L, 222L, 167L, 192L, 354L, 299L, 265L, 301L, 
341L, 316L, 289L, 267L, 250L)), .Names = c("Plant", "Year", "Length"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -25L))

   Plant Year Length
1      1    1    110
2      2    1     99
3      3    1    124
4      4    1    154
5      5    1    112
6      6    1    129
7      6    1     93    etc….
```

My question is how to perform post-hoc tests within bootstrap repetitions (and then save each test statistic, p-value and parameter value in a matrix/dataframe) in cases where there is a significant difference. I have tried the below code, but all I get is an output matrix the same length as the number of iterations, which should not be the case.

```
library(plyr)

# function to draw sample for each iteration, perform the KW test and perform post-hoc tests when differences are significant
myrandomph <- function(P,Q){
  ss <- ddply(P, .(Plant), function(x) { y <- x[sample(nrow(x), 1) ,] })
  kw <- kruskal.test(ss$Length, ss$Year)

  if(kw$p.value < 0.05){ 
    w1 <- wilcox.test(ss$Length[ss$Year =="1"], ss$Length[ss$Year =="2"], paired=FALSE)
    return(c(stat = w1$statistic, p = w1$p.value))
    w2 <- wilcox.test(ss$Length[ss$Year =="1"], ss$Length[ss$Year =="3"], paired=FALSE)
    return(c(stat = w2$statistic, p = w2$p.value))
    w3 <- wilcox.test(ss$Length[ss$Year =="2"], ss$Length[ss$Year =="3"], paired=FALSE)
    return(c(stat = w3$statistic, p = w3$p.value))
  }else{  
  return(c(stat = kw$statistic, p = kw$p.value, df = kw$parameter)) }
}

# repeat myrandomph 10 times
test_results <- do.call( rbind, replicate(10, myrandomph(df), simplify=FALSE ) )
colnames(test_results) <- c("Statistic", "P.value", "Parameter")
```

In cases where the Kruskal-Wallis test is significant, I would like to end up with a data frame row with the KW test outputs, and a row for each test output of the post-hoc tests (i.e. column with statistic values, a column with p-values, and row labels specifying which post-hoc test was run: w1, w2 or w3). In cases where the Kruskal-Wallis test is not significant, I would like only the KW statistics, p-values and parameters to be returned. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just a side note: the `boot` package provides nice functions for bootstrapping, you may want to look into that.

Comment: @ nico. thanks for the suggestion. I tried boot but ran into problems incorporating code to randomly sample only units (i.e. plants) with >1 data row.